# DateTime.ToString('o') in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, date

In C# we `DateTime.ToString('o')` for roundtrip datetime format. My question is how can achieve this in Javascript.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the some datetime format in Javascript or how to write the same function so you can use call like: `Date.toString('o')` and get the same result as you would in c# ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the MDN doc on [Date.toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), you can use this:

```
var today = new Date("05 October 2011 14:48 UTC");  
alert(today.toISOString()); // Returns 2011-10-10T14:48:00.000Z
```

Comment: Is this the format you're looking for? A specific example would. help. The MSDN doc on the ['o' format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip) does not mention the trailing Z, so my answer is probably not *exactly* what you're asking for.

Answer (score -2):

if you are looking to get the current date and time, you can use this,

```
var current = new Date();
```

Comment: They asked for how to format a date in a way useful for interchange, not how to get a date and time.